# How to return two sets of JSON data from PHP using jQuery/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to combine two of my PHP files into one to make it easier to manage my application as well as reduce the number of requests I make. I am however struggling to

1. return two sets of JSON encoded data and
2. extract the data in the AJAX Success function. Here is an abridged version of my code:

My jQuery / AJAX code where I make the request to my PHP page:

```
... .success(function(response) {
  $('input').removeClass('error').next('.errormessage').html('');
    if (!response.errors && response.result) {
      $('#contributions').html('');
      $.each(response.result, function(index, value) {
        $("#contributions").append(value);
      });
...
```

my PHP file which gets the post data, extracts stuff from the Database etc:

```
$returnResult = array("$fixedcontributions", "$percentagecontributions", "$grandtotalpercentage");

// print result for ajax request
echo json_encode(['result' => $returnResult, 'errors' => $errors]);
```

This currently works. But I have two identical functions and would like to send back another array after the ajax call and then append that value to a different div.

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
$returnResult = array("$fixedcontributions", "$percentagecontributions", "$grandtotalpercentage");
$returnResult2 = array("hi", "test", "please", "work");

$returnresultall = array("$returnResult", "$returnResult2");
echo json_encode(['result' => $returnresultall, 'errors' => $errors]);
```

```js
.success(function(response) {
  $('input').removeClass('error').next('.errormessage').html('');
  if (!response.errors && response.result) {
    $('#deductions').html('');
    $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
      $("#deductions").append(value[0]);
      $("#contributions").append(value[1]);
   });
```

When I check what is returned in the console, I get:

```
{result: ["Array", "Array"], errors: false}
```

Comment: Try without quotes around $returnResult and $returnResult2.

Comment: I tried that but I get the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: don't put quotes around the 2 array variables

Comment: I think I have made progress. I did what you said but now I am unable to properly display the data. `$.each(response.result, function( index, value) {  $("#contributions").append(value[0]); ` repeats the same value twice.

Comment: So you are at least getting data returned now for both arrays? Make sure that your dataType is set to json. Your each function looks correct in that it should be printing the first value of each object ($fixedcontributions and 'hi').

Comment: Or you could use the success callback function that gives you the json result as parameter. `success : function(data, status){$('#selector').html(data['result']);}`

Comment: @BKirby Thanks, it seems to be working but I think I need to rethink my approach here as it is confusing. Thanks for your help

Comment: @zenko That seems like something I understand, I will definitely try that. Thanks for your help.